# Arithmetic sequence.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

> Consider the numbers $37,44,51,...,177$, which form an arithmetic sequence.  A number $n$ is the sum of five distinct numbers from this sequence. How many possible values of $n$ are there?

My attempt,

I assume that the sequence is $1,2,3,4,5,...,21.$
So $1+2+3+4+5=15 $ which is the smallest and $17+18+19+20+21=95$ which is the largest.

So $n=15$~$21$

So there are $81$ possible numbers.

I've checked with the solution, and apparently $81$ is the correct answer. The proposed solution which is the totally not same with mine. Can anyone check with my solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sequence has $36$ terms,  not $21$.

Comment: @JaideepKhare really? $\frac{177-37}{7}=20$

Comment: $(177-37)/7+1=21$

Comment: @Mathxx Oh sorry, I did $44-37=4$.My mind was on vacation writing that.

Comment: From the  21 distinct objects, we are going to take 5 to form a sum n. There are C(21, 5) possible n's.

Comment: @Mick I remember you. If I'm not mistaken, you wrote the answer for the American vs Russian question long time ago.

Comment: @Mathxx Yes. That me. Hope you like that post. But this time, please ignore the above comment because I noticed that some of the sums are not distinct.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, because every term of your sequence can be bijectively mapped using the rule $S=30+7n$ onto the other sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution by the author.

The common difference of the given sequence is $7$, and there are $21$ terms in the sequence, since $\frac{177-37}{7}=20$. Let $n$ be a sum of five terms in the sequence; that is $$n=185+7(a+b+c+d+e)$$
where $a,b,c,d$ and $e$ are distinct elements of the set $[0,1,2,...,19,20]$. Let $X=a+b+c+d+e$. Since we want to count the number of different possible values of $n$, it suffices to count the number of possible values of $X$. The least possible value of $X=0+1+2+3+4=10$ and the largest possible value of $X$ is $16+17+18+19+20=90$

Thus, every integer from $10$ to $90$ is a possible value of $X$. SInce $10$ and $90$ are the smallest and largest possible values of $X$, respectively, there are $90-10+1=81$ possible values of $X$ and so $81$ possible value of $n$

Comment: Your solution is the essentially the same as the author's. You are counting number of different possible sums from a set of $[1,2,3,\cdots, 21]$ whilst he is counting from the set of $[0,1,2,\cdots, 20]$. Since both sets are integer sequences and have the same number of elements, the count will be the same.